# Proving existence and uniqueness of solutions of this IVP: $x'(t)=f(x(t))+\sin(t)$, with $x(0)=0$ and $f\in C^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

I'm doing this exercise:

> Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function such that $\|f\|_\infty\leq M$. Prove that \begin{cases}x'(t)=f(x(t))+\sin(t) \\ x(0)=0\end{cases} has an **unique solution** defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

What we can tell about $f(x(t))+\sin(t)$ is that it's locally Lipschitz, but that only gives us locally uniqueness.

I've already proved that solutions have to be defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, but I don't know how can we show uniqueness.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: glue the uniqueness patches, just like existence.

Comment: @user10354138 I think I understand what do you mean, but can you formally do this argument? From that starting point of an open neighbourhood where our solution is unique